# Fast api mongodb how to return documents array

Tags: mongodb, fastapi

I am trying to create and read simple user. Create user is working fine but read is throwing error of jsonable_encoder

My code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from models.user import User
from config.database import user_collection

router = APIRouter(prefix="/auth", tags=['auth'])


@router.get("/get-all-users")
async def get_all_users():
    users = user_collection.find()
    return users


@router.post("/create-user")
async def create_user(data: User):
    user_data = dict(data)
    result = user_collection.insert_one(user_data)
    return {**user_data, "id": str(result.inserted_id)}
```

I think in users I need to convert in json or something but not sure how to do this in best way.

Answer (score 1):

Pymongo's find() returns a cursor object (pymongo.cursor.Cursor). That's not the end result you are looking for; it's an iterator. If you return that directly, fastAPI will run the jsonable_encoder (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/) on it and try to convert it to something that can be encoded to json. It fails, because it doesn't support MongoDB cursors.

You could get a list of users instead, by using something like:
users = [user for user in user_collection.find()]
and then return that.